# Alternative to PHPMyAdmin Export

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql

I would like to export the results of a SELECT query as valid SQL INSERTS and import it into another database (some records were accidentally deleted). Normally I would use PHPMyAdmin's Export feature, but PHPMyAdmin is not available on one of the servers. I believe I can use a [VIEW](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) and mysqldump but I'm not sure where to start -- I can't find documentation stating how to dump just my view.

Comment: Check here..It is Open Source Web Tool...It Might solve your Problem... [Click HERE](http://mywebsql.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you're importing into one table 1:1, you can export it to a CSV file and then import the results.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/table.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Then you can import it manually by doing

```
load data local infile 'table.csv' into table your_new_table fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
(your, field, names)
```

Comment: why not use the mysql default values, insted of specifing them on both side?

Comment: I thought it would be a more complete answer to show the values, as the OP might want to customize his output.

Comment: Does it have to go to a CSV file first? Can I just output SQL INSERT statements?

Comment: You could certainly do that. Something like `INSERT INTO your_table(field1) SELECT (field1)`. Just modify your query to fit your needs. I'd strongly suggest going the C2V route though -- You have a tangible file that you can examine if something goes awry.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/yourData.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

This will output to a file in a csv format. You can also return the data in the type you want.

Answer (score -1):

just append `INTO OUTFILE "filename"` after your query, and you get a file with the content on that server, that you can load into the other server